# Need nav bar to stick to top of window Foundation 6

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm having trouble getting the Nav bar to stay on top of window. I've tried using the "sticky data" but nothing. No matter what i do it keeps scrolling along with the page. I've also tried to add the class to small and medium navs. Any suggestions?

Html:

```
    <!-- Small Navigation -->
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="nav-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
    <a class="logo-small show-for-small-only" href="#"><img src="/assets/img/fingerLogoXS.gif" /></a>
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>
<!-- Medium-Up Navigation -->
<nav class="top-bar" id="nav-menu">
    <div class="logo-wrapper hide-for-small-only">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/assets/img/fingerLogoSM.2.gif">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class="has-submenu">
                <a href="#">Technologies</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu vertical medium-horizontal" data-submenu>
                    <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<!--End Main Navigation-->
```

Css:

```
    /* Small Navigation */

.logo-small {
  float: right;
  padding: 4px;
}

.title-bar {
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  background-color: #3D3242;
}

.menu-icon,
.title-bar-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
}

/* Medium-Up Navigation */
@media only screen and (min-width: 40rem) { 

    .sticky {
  width: 100%;
}

  .logo-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

  .logo-wrapper .logo {
    width: 92px;
    height:  92px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: -6px;
    margin-left: -46px;
  }

  // Right part
  .top-bar-right {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 60px;
  }

  .top-bar-right ul {
    float:  left;
  }

  // Left part
  .top-bar-left {
    width:  50%;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }

  .top-bar-left ul {
    float:  right;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Website: http://adolfobarreto.atwebpages.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was helped by the good folks over at the Zurb Foundation forum. Here is the proper way to implement a sticky TopBar:

```
   <div data-sticky-container>
  <div class="small-12 sticky" data-sticky data-options="marginTop: 0">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
          <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">One</a>
            <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks Again Val!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **working solution** to what you asked: https://jsfiddle.net/368z4fun/

Easily solved using `position:fixed;` like so:

```
.title-bar {
  position:fixed;
}

nav {
  position:fixed;
}
```

Also added some more CSS to fix the styles for the `fixed` change. Beware of old mobile browser compatibility using `position:fixed;` you'll probably need a fix like [this](https://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/).

You can also use a browser plugin like StyleBot to check this on your live site. Look at this:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly. I need the nav bar to stay in the window as i scroll. In other words not scroll up with the window.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, yes you did! I was missing a semicolon...lol. Thank you

Comment: No problem, have fun.